# Form upload with CI Youtube Data Api by Jim Saunders

Tags: api, codeigniter, upload, youtube

I'm buildig an website in CI.
I want to upload a movie to YouTube with the help of CI YouTube API coded by Jim Saunders.

The problem is, when I want to upload a movie from a html-form, I always getting this error by doing this:

EX: `$videoPath = $_POST['myvideo'];`

```
Severity: Warning
Message: file_get_contents(Wildlife.wmv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: libraries/youtube.php
Line Number: 487
```

but when I change the Path-directory for the movie to a URL, it works.
EX: `$videoPath = 'www.somesite.com/myvideo.mp4'`;

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are uploading has to exist on your server already and the path has to be to the file on your server. Form uploads wont work in this case, it looks like you should use getUploadToken.

directUpload Takes a file on your server and sends it to YouTube.

getUploadToken Gets a token from YouTube to perform an upload from an HTML form to YouTube.

I can see where the wording is a bit confusing. Read up on upload tokens in the youtube developer docs.

[EDIT] This is the link for doing browser based uploads. http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html

The library will handle steps 1 and 2 for you. You must then use the response to complete step 3 in your own code.

Comment: Ok, I used the getFormUploadToken() method and now I receive a URL and a Token. What is the next step?

Comment: Here is the link for browser based uploading, in particular actually creating a form to upload a file: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html#Uploading_the_Video_File